# how can I get the processor ID of the current process in C in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a program that needs to know what logical processor it's running on.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790682/) tells me how to do it in assembly, while [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347909/) tells me how to use this code in assembly without translating it to AT&T syntax.

Is there an easier way to do this using existing Linux system calls or library functions, or is it necessary for me to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: You could get that info but I'm not sure how long that info would be good as you could easily have that process rescheduled and run on another core at any time.

Comment: The question you refer to doesn't do what you want. It tells you how many CPUs there are, not which CPU you're running on.

Comment: @ugoren: you're right... I misread it

Comment: follow this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491566/getting-the-machine-serial-number-and-cpu-id-using-c-c-in-linux

Comment: @HosseinBobarshad: That's a different thing entirely.  My question is about the logical processor ID of the logical processor that the thread is running on, while the question you pointed me to is about the model of the processor, and perhaps its serial number.

Answer (score 10):

There's the linux specific [`getcpu` call](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getcpu.2.html).

Comment: Note that it gives you the cpu at the time of the call. The next instruction, your thread might be on another CPU.

Comment: @ugoren of course! :) unless one uses `sched_setaffinity` http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity

Comment: Note that `getcpu` may be implemented in userspace (rather than as a syscall) via vdso, so it's possibly less expensive than you would expect.

Comment: And glibc has wrapper for this called `sched_getcpu`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10256090/895245

Answer (score 7):

Tou can see [sched_getcpu()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sched_getcpu.3.html). This glibc C function calls the `getcpu` Linux system call.

Comment: Minimal runnable example demonstrating interaction with `sched_setaffinity`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280909/how-to-set-cpu-affinity-for-a-process-from-c-or-c-in-linux/54478296#54478296

Answer (score -2):

Try this , i am not sure that what you want is this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/utsname.h>

int main()
{

char hostname[1024];
struct utsname userinfo;
if(uname(&userinfo)>=0)
{
  printf("\n***** System Details ******\n");
  printf("System Name    : %s\n",userinfo.sysname);
  printf("System Node    : %s\n",userinfo.nodename);
  printf("System Release : %s\n",userinfo.release);
  printf("System Version : %s\n",userinfo.version);
  printf("System Machine : %s\n",userinfo.machine);
}
else
 printf("\nSystem details fetch failed..\n");



if(gethostname(&hostname,1024)==0)
{
  printf("Hostname : %s\n",hostname);
}
else
 printf("\nHostname details fetch failed..\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That will give me the IP for the machine.  I'm looking for the id of the core in the CPU that my process is running in.

Comment: is there any way to get the CPU ID or other kind hardware address? Specially for iPhone?